# Game not launching (missing executable)

Tags: technical-issues, pc, quantum-break

I am trying to play Quantum Break (on Steam), but whenever I launch the game, I get a missing executable error message.

I checked the Quantum Break files and there isn't any .exe in the root folder. The _CommonRedist folders are also empty. Under "data", the config and timelinerec folders don't have anything in them either. Additionally, there is nothing in the dx11 folder out in the root directory.

I reinstalled the newest version of Visual C++ just in case too, even though that wouldn't fix the missing files. Validating the Steam cache of the game says that all of the files are there, which is most likely not true.

Anything I should try?

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Did you try deleting the local game files and downloading / re-installing the game?

Comment: @Colin Yes I have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Repairing the library folder solved the issue for me.

To repair the Steam library folder, go to Steam>Settings>Downloads>Steam Library Folders.

Click on that and it will open a menu. Right click on the Steam library folder that has Quantum Break installed inside of it.

Click repair and wait for the program to finish, the command line application will disappear once done.

Quantum Break will reinstall and the game should work normally.